# How does .closest and how to modify it to pick another class that is not the closest?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that checks if form inputs are valid or not. Then it adds a class called 'has-error' to a .form-group class if there is an error.

I don't fully understand how it picks the correct .form-group but i suspect "closest" means it goes back until it finds the first one then applies it:

```
allNextBtn.click(function(){
  var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
      curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
      nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
      curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url'],input[type='radio'],Select"),
      isValid = true;

  $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
  for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
      if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
          isValid = false;
          $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
          ???$(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");???
      }
  }

  if (isValid)
      nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
```

});

So this works for example:

```
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Surname</label>*
        <input id="Surname" name="Surname" maxlength="100" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text">
      </div>
```

Now I have a radio button and I am trying to work out either A) how to change my HTML code to match the same structure as the text box input above or B) what to add to the script between ???.....??? to add the class 'has-error' to the label on line 2 below. It adds it to the two labels below the input which is good (as I guess these are the 'closest') but not the first one :

```
<div class="col-md-12"> 
<label class="control-label">Gender</label>*
<div class="form-group funkyradio">
    <div class="form-group funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="GenderRadio" id="radio1" required="required" />
        <label class="control-label" for="radio1">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="GenderRadio" id="radio2" required="required"/>
        <label class="control-label" for="radio2">Female</label>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

EDIT:

So this modification works:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12"> 
<label class="control-label">Gender</label>*
<div class="funkyradio">
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="M" id="radio1" required="required" />
        <label class="control-label" for="radio1">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="F" id="radio2" required="required"/>
        <label class="control-label" for="radio2">Female</label>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Though I'd still be interested to know what to put between ???...??? if i wanted to target another element on the page somewhere, perhaps this?:

```
(curInputs[i]).find?("#div-with-unique-ID").addClass("has-error");
```

Comment: The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) state: _For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree._ Can you just remove the `form-group` class from the individual radio button items? That should give the result you want.

Comment: @dave thank you. that worked.

ill post my code answer in my question as no space here.

Comment: Though I'd still be interested to know what to put between ???...??? if i wanted to target another element on the page somewhere, perhaps this?:

(curInputs[i]).find?("#div-with-unique-ID").addClass("has-error");